# How the order of arguments works in a reduce helper method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
// this is the array
var numbers = [10,20,30];
// Now I want to get the sum of all the elements of numbers array
// this will give 60 
numbers.reduce(function(sum,number){
    return sum + number; 
},0);

// this also gives 60
numbers.reduce(function(number,sum){
    return sum + number;
},0);
```

I am just learning ES6, I tried looking at MDN but couldn't find the explanation. I just want to know how javascript detects the argument with initial value to be zero and which it detects to be the array elements.
Or does it arbitrarily chooses the argument values.

Comment: The names that you give the arguments are just for your benefit. The accumulated value will always be the first argument, and the current element will always be the second argument. The reason both of your examples result in the same sum is because addition is commutative. Whether you add `0 + 10` (as in your first case), or `10 + 0` (as in your second case), the result is still 10.

Comment: I don't see any ES6 in your code? That's all just plain valid ES5 as well.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: Try with a non-commutative operator, like string concatenation.

Comment: Try it with subtraction, which isn't commutative either.

Comment: btw, where are you getting `60` as result?

Comment: @NinaScholz I changed the array by adding the last element, that's where you didn't get the 60. The array is [10,20,30]. And yeah I got the concept.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, the first argument will always be the sum/accumulator, and the second will be the value.

Both parameters have no inherit binding to a name, so you can name both the sum and the value whatever you wish.

In your example, the first one works probably as you expected, with the sum as the first parameter and the value as the second parameter. In your second example, it works the exact same way, the only difference being that you named the 'sum' as 'number' and the 'value' as 'sum'.

JS may be weird but it's not messing with your arguments in this case. You're just naming the arguments differently.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce/):

> The first time the callback is called, accumulator and currentValue
>   can be one of two values. If initialValue is provided in the call to
>   reduce, then accumulator will be equal to initialValue, and
>   currentValue will be equal to the first value in the array. If no
>   initialValue is provided, then accumulator will be equal to the first
>   value in the array, and currentValue will be equal to the second.
>
> Note: If initialValue isn't provided, reduce will execute the callback
>   function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If
>   initialValue is provided, it will start at index 0.

The first param, "sum", is the accumulator. The second param, currentValue, is "number".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax of the `reduce` method.

```
array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)
```

where, function is used to reduce the array and will be invoked for each array element.

This function uses **first** argument passed to it as an accumulator to store the result.

Each element of the array will be passed as the **second** argument to the function.

Just like other functions in JavaScript, the order of the parameters matter(not their name).

While these two parameters are required to be present in your function, it can have two more optional parameters, viz `currentIndex` and the `array` itself.

And finally, the optional `initValue` passes to reduce function will be used to initialize the accumulator.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp).